# Intersection of a dataframe with a list of columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, intersection

I need to intersect the dataframe columns with the database columns (defined in a list) before I execute a query.
My current code looks like this:

```
db_columns_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
dataframe = dataframe[dataframe.columns & db_columns_list]
```

This works well, but I am getting the warning:

```
*FutureWarning: Index.__and__ operating as a set operation is deprecated, in the future this will be a logical operation matching Series.__and__.  Use index.intersection(other) instead
  dataframe = dataframe[dataframe.columns & db_columns_list]*
```

So I would like to convert it into something like:

```
dataframe = dataframe[dataframe.columns.intersection(db_columns_list)]
```

but with that I get the error:

```
*Unresolved attribute reference 'intersection' for class 'Iterator'*
```

Please note that the database may contain more columns than the dataframe.
Therefore I believe the intersection is the correct way to approach this.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

`intersection` function can be applied as below.

Toy example,

```
db_columns_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df=DataFrame({
    'col1':[1,2],
    'col3':[3,4]
})

## Solution
df[set(df.columns).intersection(set(db_columns_list))]

# Improved version with the help of `Mustafa Aydın` 
df[df.columns.intersection(db_columns_list)]
```

**Output**

```
    col3    col1
0   3       1
1   4       2
```

Comment: `pd.Index` has an intersection method and works without casting to `set`. Your example works without both `set`s. I think the issue is different

Comment: pd.Index has all the functionality of the set plus more for example - It's ordered and it can contain duplicates as well. So, I guess the problem is diff. here as suggested by @MustafaAydın

Comment: The new solution proposed: df[df.columns.intersection(db_columns_list)]   for me does not work. I get: Unresolved attribute reference 'intersection' for class 'Iterator'.  The previous one with set worked.

Comment: @Forna Added both solutions for now, which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Pandas version 1.2.3

Comment: The true solution is what works for OP I guess,  +1  :) (downvote isn't me, btw)

Comment: nw, Thanks for +1, We are here to help each other. It's okay if someone  downvotes(his choice).

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code will fix your issue.Intersection works only for sets

```
common_cols = list(set(dataframe.columns).intersection(set(db_columns_list)))

dataframe = dataframe[common_cols]
```

Comment: conversion to list may not be required.